# Simple java API Dog

Tags: java

new to programming - I have a question : I am trying to create a  data type Dog

public class Dog

How do i  construct an empty Dog type? 
I have this so far :

```
  public Dog()
  { 
this.Dog=" " ;
  }
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Creating an Empty Dog instance

if you have a class like:

```
  public class Dog {
    private int age;

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

A new empty dog can be created by declaring a new Dog instance:

```
Dog doggy = new Dog();
```

the doggy will not have any values, it will be a blank Dog.

### Adding and Retrieving values from Dog instance

values can be added to the dog by doing:

```
doggy.setAge(15);
```

and then if you want to retrieve that age value you can do:

```
System.out.println("my doggy is" + doggy.getAge()+" years old");
```

Comment: thank you , do you know any sites that  can help me learn java- using data types /constructing it?

Comment: There's plenty of java books out there. But that never really did anything for me, I always try to learn by doing hands on stuff. Trying to solve something, and when I cant figure out the specific part googling away to try and understand. With that said try http://codingbat.com/ they have a lot of different problems.

Answer (score 0):

To create an empty constructor, you just need `public Dog() {}`